# Is it possible to fire more than one tag with 'Page View' trigger?

Tags: google-tag-manager

folks.

I am new to GTM and in need of help. I am trying to fire 2 different tags using the trigger 'Page view'. Is that possible? One of them is firing, the other is not!

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible. If you can give some information on your setup we find be able to help you to find the actual problem.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem or are there still problems in this scope?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitly possible a trigger can fire as many tags as you want.

They should fire if you added the trigger to your tag. Maybe the tag itself isn't defined as it should so that's the reason you don't see it in the debugger.

Don't forget to save your changes after adding stuff.